# get Kendo column text value

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

im trying to get the Text value of the metric_nme column and if this was equal to 'Accounts Audit' hiding the Update button...

does anyone knows how can i get the value of the column in kendo grid?

here if me code...

```js
$("#assessmentGrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: gridDS,
        navigatable: true,
        noRecords: {
            template: "No assessments were found"
        },
        filterable: true,
        sortable: {
            mode: 'single',
            allowUnsort: false
        },
        columns: [
                    { field: 'assessment_pk', hidden: true },
                    { field: 'role_fk', hidden: true },
                    { field: 'role_nme', title: 'Role', width: 120 },
                    { field: 'metric_fk', hidden: true },
                    { field: 'assess_dte', hidden: true },
                    {
                        field: 'metric_nme', title: 'Metric', width: 150,
                        validation: {
                            metric_nme_validation: function (input) {
                                if (dataItem[metric_nme] = 'Accounts Audit') {
                                   // attributes: { 'class': 'k-grid-update' }.
                                    $("#k-grid-update").data("kendoGrid").visible = false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        
                    },
                    { field: 'assess_val', title: 'Score', width: 80, template: "#= (returnUnitMetricID(metric_fk) == 2) ? parseInteger(assess_val, 10) : assess_val #", attributes: { 'style': 'text-align: right' } },
                    { field: 'adjust_val', title: 'Manager Score', width: 100, template: "#= (returnUnitMetricID(metric_fk) == 2) ? parseInteger(adjust_val, 10) : adjust_val #", attributes: { 'style': 'text-align: right' } },
                    { field: 'adjust_by', title: 'Adjusted By', width: 120 },
                    { field: 'comment_txt', title: 'Comment', hidden: true },
                    { field: 'rating_cde', title: 'Rating', width: 95 },
                    { field: 'adjusted_fk', hidden: true },
                    { field: 'pct_to_goal', title: '% to Goal', width: 100, template: '#=kendo.format("{0:p}", pct_to_goal / 100)#', attributes: { 'style': 'text-align: right' } },
                    { field: 'lastupdate_by', title: 'Last Update By', width: 100 },
                    { field: 'lastupdate_on', title: 'Last Update On', width: 130, template: "#= (lastupdate_on == null) ? '' : kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(lastupdate_on, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss') #" },
                    {
                        command: {
                            text: "Update",
                            click: updateScore,

                        }, title: " ", width: "60",
                        attributes: { 'class': 'k-grid-update' }
                    }
        ],
    }).find("table").on("keydown", onGridKeydown);
    
    function updateScore(e) {
    e.preventDefault(e);
    clearWindowPopUpFields();
    $(".k-window").css('height', '420px');

    $(".alert").hide();

    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));

    var assestmentDate = new Date(dataItem.assess_dte);
    $("#lbAssessmentDateRO").text($("#txtPeriod").val());

    $('#lblMetric').text(dataItem.metric_nme);
    $('#lblRole').text(dataItem.role_nme);
    metricFk = dataItem.metric_fk;
    $('#txtAssociate').text($('#cbAssociate').data("kendoComboBox").text());
    switchScoreTypeControl(returnUnitMetricID(dataItem.metric_fk));

    if (dataItem.assessment_pk == null) {
        addScorePopUp(dataItem);
    } else {
        updateScorePopUp(dataItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: please answer ...

Comment: Do you want to hide the whole column or just a value for the added/edited row. Can you describe the flow and desired output, please?

Comment: i just need to get the column value when grid is loaded and compare it to 'Accounts Audit' text and if this was true , i want to hide Update button ...

Comment: By the column value, you mean the cell value, right? So you have an action per row and for example if in a row value of column 'a' equals to '123' then you want to hide the 'update', am I right ?

Comment: yes that's right

Answer (score 0):

You can use `visible` parameter:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.command.visible

Here is an example:

http://dojo.telerik.com/ACopA

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/custom-command">
  <style>
    html {
      font-size: 14px;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
  </style>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.223/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.223/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.223/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />

  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.223/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.223/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="../content/shared/js/people.js"></script>

  <div id="example">
    <div id="grid"></div>

    <div id="details"></div>

    <script>
      var wnd,
        detailsTemplate;

      $(document).ready(function() {

        var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
          dataSource: {
            pageSize: 20,
            data: createRandomData(50)
          },
          pageable: true,
          height: 550,
          columns: [{
              field: "FirstName",
              title: "First Name",
              width: "140px"
            },
            {
              field: "LastName",
              title: "Last Name",
              width: "140px"
            },
            {
              field: "Title"
            },
            {
              command: [{
                text: "View Details",
                click: showDetails,
                visible: function(dataItem) {
                  return dataItem.LastName.charAt(0) !== "D"
                }
              }]
            }
          ]
        }).data("kendoGrid");

        wnd = $("#details")
          .kendoWindow({
            title: "Customer Details",
            modal: true,
            visible: false,
            resizable: false,
            width: 300
          }).data("kendoWindow");

        detailsTemplate = kendo.template($("#template").html());
      });

      function showDetails(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
        wnd.content(detailsTemplate(dataItem));
        wnd.center().open();
      }
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
      <div id="details-container">
        <h2>#= FirstName # #= LastName #</h2>
        <em>#= Title #</em>
        <dl>
          <dt>City: #= City #</dt>
          <dt>Birth Date: #= kendo.toString(BirthDate, "MM/dd/yyyy") #</dt>
        </dl>
      </div>
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
      #details-container {
        padding: 10px;
      }
      
      #details-container h2 {
        margin: 0;
      }
      
      #details-container em {
        color: #8c8c8c;
      }
      
      #details-container dt {
        margin: 0;
        display: inline;
      }
    </style>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```